# Free hand Drawring on JFrame, Color + Point[] Storage and rendering failing

Tags: java, arrays, rendering, repaint, onpaint

The following program is supposed to allow free hand drawing on the one frame and the other as a button to open the color selector. The code for the main class can be found:

```
package clickTesting;

import Desksnap.Utils.Line;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {
    public static Color currentColor = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Viewer gui = new Viewer();
        button gui1 = new button();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui1.setVisible(true);
        boolean lol = true;
        while (lol) {
            gui.repaint(500);
        }
    }


    static class Viewer extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
        public List<Line> lines = new LinkedList<Line>();
        private int index = 0;
        private Point[] arr = new Point[100000];

        public Viewer() {
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            PhotoWindow = new JFrame();
            setUndecorated(true);
            {
                Container PhotoWindowContentPane = PhotoWindow.getContentPane();
                PhotoWindowContentPane.setLayout(null);
                PhotoWindowContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 539));
                PhotoWindow.pack();
                PhotoWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(PhotoWindow.getOwner());
                addMouseListener(this);


            }
        }

        private JFrame PhotoWindow;


        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            arr[index] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            index++;
            System.out.println(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            lines.add(new Line(Main.currentColor, arr));
            arr = new Point[100000];
            index = 0;
            System.out.println("Released");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            arr[index] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            index++;
            System.out.println(index);
        }


        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponents(g);
            if (lines.size() >= 0) {
                for (Line z : lines) {
                    if (z != null) {
                        Point[] lel = z.getLine();
                        g.setColor(z.getColor());
                        if (lel != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < lel.length; i++)
                                if (lel[i] != null) {
                                    g.drawLine(lel[i].x, lel[i].y, lel[i + 1].x, lel[i + 1].y);
                                }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Nope");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nothing In List Yet!");
            }
        }


        //Unused
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }


    public static class button extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
        public button() {
            this.addMouseListener(this);
            this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            PhotoWindow = new JFrame();
            setUndecorated(true);
            {
                Container PhotoWindowContentPane = PhotoWindow.getContentPane();
                PhotoWindowContentPane.setLayout(null);
                PhotoWindowContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 539));
                PhotoWindow.pack();
                PhotoWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(PhotoWindow.getOwner());
                addMouseListener(this);
            }
        }

        private JFrame PhotoWindow;


        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JColorChooser color = new JColorChooser();
            Main.currentColor = color.showDialog(
                    button.this,
                    "Choose Background Color",
                    Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

This class supports the drawing, recording of the lines and the main loop:

```
package Desksnap.Utils;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;


public class Line {
    Color color = null;
    Point[] points = null;

 public Line(Color color, Point[] points){
     color = this.color;
     points = this.points;
 }

    public Color getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public Point[] getLine(){
        return points;
    }


}
```

This is the line class used.

After drawing a line the program just prints 'Nope' into the console.

> Output: Nope x 10000000

Please help me understand what I've done wrong.

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: See this `while (lol) {gui.repaint(500);}` this is `while (true) { System.out.println("Very Bad");}`!  You do not control the painting process within Swing, Swing will tell you when it wants something painted and you will respond to that request.  `repaint` is a "request" you make to the `RepaintManager` to inform it that you would like be update when it deems it appropriate.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details on the painting

Comment: haha :P Thanks for the edit/cleanup of the post, i'm new to the site and didn't really want to try and over complicate it by messing it all up :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, NEVER do this...

```
while (lol) {
    gui.repaint(500);
}
```

You do not control the paint process, that is the domain of the `RepaintManager`.  If you want your component updated, use `repaint` ONCE and let the `RepaintManager` figure it out.

The core of your problem is here...

```
public Line(Color color, Point[] points) {
    color = this.color;
    points = this.points;
}
```

You are assigning the values of `this.color` to `color` and `this.points` to `points`, which has no effect.  You should be assigning them the other way around (`color` to `this.color`)

You will, also want to take a closer look at:

- [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Calling `super.paintComponents` from within `paint` is a bad idea, you should be calling `super.paint` and let it take care of the appropriate paint calls.

Actually, you shouldn't be overriding `paint` without a really good reason, espically of top level containers.  Instead, start by extending your paint class from a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead.

You can then add this component to what ever container you want.

Comment: Thank-You very much! This fixed the nope problem and seems to override all problems leading up to it.

The multi GUI is only until i put a button on the main one, this isn't the program i'm working on just an aspect of it in a very basic/bad form for the sake of tetsing.

the only problem is now after drawring/releasing it won't draw on the frame anymore XD

Comment: I see ^_^ worked for the first line but didn't draw any other's , just pulled errors

Comment: You array is up to `10000` elements long, which is filled with `null` values to begin with.  In you paint loop, you are not check to see if the next point is `null` (and you will need to check for `index + 1` as well)...This would be better server with a `LinkedList`...

Comment: Hey, dunno if you're still around but I have ran into another problem, your help so far has been wonderful and my project is going great: 
my current code: 
Main:
http://pastebin.com/NTMkap80
Line:
http://pastebin.com/mAK74gZs
and my new error is:
http://pastebin.com/8AjyCY2A
Thank-you very much in advanced !

Comment: Edit: Removing all of the i+1 i-1's made the code error free and working fine but the lines are dotted and no actual solid lines, so close but yet so far...<3 plz halp

Comment: Re Edit: I found the problem, silly mistake of calling a index which was non existant/inpossible, now all i need is to thicken this line ^_^

Comment: Yep, was going to mention grouping each two points to form a line, discard any mismatching pairs (so if you end up with a `Point` and `null` you'd throw it away) ;)